# How do I correctly patchValues in my FormGroup object from my URL params?

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, formgroups

I'm using `activatedRoute` and subscribing to params in a component.
If my params where: `?food=burger&drink=beer&dessert=icecream`
then my queryParams object:

```
{
food: "burger",
drink: "beer",
....
}
```

Some background - I have a `FormGroup` which has these value keys as controls and is displayed for users in a dropdown component. The User selects from dropdown and the url is changed based off those selections.

I do have my `FormGroup` defined in this component.

`public filterFormGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({});`

I call a method in the `NgOnInit` to add controls:

```
 this.filterFormGroup.addControl('food', new FormControl());
 this.filterFormGroup.addControl('drink', new FormControl());
 this.filterFormGroup.addControl('dessert', new FormControl());
```

Also in the `NgOnInIt` is when I try `patchValue`, to update the dropdown(the `FormGroup`) with the latest url params

Main goal is if the user copies and pastes the url, the filters reflect what is in the url. If they were to type: beefstew for food, they would see that selection marked in the dropdown.

and this happens right after the subscription so full code here:

```
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
      const queryParams = {};
      params.keys.forEach((key) => {
        const value = params.get(key);
        if (value) {
          queryParams[key] = value;
          
        }
      });
      this.filterFormGroup.patchValue(queryParams, {emitEvent: true})
```

I've looked at the documentation and think I'm passing it in correctly but I get this error:

```
    at t._assignValue (select.mjs:707:22)
    at t.writeValue (select.mjs:465:14)
    at e (forms.mjs:3165:27)
    at forms.mjs:3651:50
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Ss.setValue (forms.mjs:3651:28)
    at Ss.patchValue (forms.mjs:3656:14)
    at forms.mjs:2790:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I've tried `setValue` but it gives the same error. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and let me know it is working or not::

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
```

Inside your component class add this::

```
filterForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  food: [''],
  drink: [''],
  dessert: [''],
});

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    const value: { [key: string]: any } = {};
    params.keys.forEach((key) => {
      value[key] = params.get(key);
    });

    this.filterForm.patchValue(value);

    console.log(this.filterForm.value);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here is the error after trying that code: 

`ERROR TypeError: o.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Can you please upload your project on stackblitz and let me check it?